# kgdb fail to start

Tags: kgdb

I'm struglling for some time to make kgdb work in my sytsem, but meanwhile it does not.
I'm using TI's SDK which based on 2.6.37 git.
When trying to work with serial, I always get the following exception:

I've tried kgdb in 2 modes, but both fail:

**1) from boot:**
I added in bootargs with:

```
"kgdboc=ttyO0,115200 kgdbwait".

------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at drivers/serial/serial_core.c:399 uart_get_baud_rate+0x124/0x138()
Modules linked in:
Backtrace:
[<c004ffc4>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c03ee140>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c04f4d9f r5:0000018f r4:00000000 r3:60000013
```

**2) from console:**

```
root@dm814x:~# echo ttyS0 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
kgdb: Registered I/O driver kgdboc.


root@dm814x:~# echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
SysRq : DEBUG
Entering KGDB
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
pgd = c4368000
[00000000] *pgd=84042031, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 80000007 [#1]
last sysfs file: /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
KGDB: re-enter exception: ALL breakpoints killed
Backtrace:
```

The kernel config use:

```
CONFIG_KGDB

CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL
```

Is there any guess what the problem is ?
Maybe I need to patch the kernel with kgdb appropriate patch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also a null pointer dereference when trying with ttyS0. It showed up that I had to specify ttyO0 instead of ttyS0. I see that you wrote ttyO0 in your setup during boot and ttyS0 in your alternative interactive setup after boot which might reveal some confusion about this topic. So, please clarify which tty you are using. For more information generally about KDB as frontend to kgdb see http://elinux.org/KDB
That helped me a lot because it is a detailed description including examples also how to configure the kernel to use at least most of the features of kgdb/kdb.

Comment: That's Right , now it works !